# AppHarbor Test Execution configuration

Tags: testing, nunit, appharbor, specflow

I'm writing some specflow tests to drive out my systems behaviour. All working great locally. However, when I commit to git and AppHarbor builds it fails. At present it's due to a lack of transformations identifying the appharbor hosted app.

However, everytime I write a new feature with accompanying specflow (and selenium) tests, I anticipate that my specflow tests will fail because the new feature has not yet been deployed. Viscious circle.

I'd actually like to constrain the build somehow to not run the specflow tests. Is there a way with AppHarbor of constraining which tests run? Nunit categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AppHarbor's solution file convention](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/build-process-and-solution-file-convention) to achieve this. If you have a separate project containing the specflow/selenium tests the trick is to make sure that this project is not referenced in the solution we build.

More specifically you can create a solution with the name `AppHarbor.sln` and reference only the web, console and test projects you want AppHarbor to build and test from this solution file. AppHarbor will always prefer building a solution with that name if it's found in your repository.

You can then maintain a separate solution file (likely the one you're already using) for development where the project containing the specflow/selenium tests is included. This will allow you to execute your tests locally before committing and retain your current workflow.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll give it a try. One consideration if you'll entertain me. I'd like to eventually run the specflow tests post deployment, i.e. when the latest features hit the site, which will have accompanying specflow tests. I think I'm correct in saying that there's no way to do this? I guess the build pipeline is intentionally lightweight, build, test deploy, and therefore not configurable. I'd guess I'll just need to set up my own team city instance to do such tasks, and then run specflow tests against my prod from my CI server post deployment.

Comment: You're right, there's currently no way to perform tests on the actual running website as part of the build/test process. You may however be able to integrate with for instance [Sauce Labs](https://saucelabs.com/) to perform tests against the live site.You might want to run a development/staging app for the the tests, so they can run from either an external service or your own CI server post deployment (but before pushing to your production site).